# PageMethods is not calling on success or on failure function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, pagemethods

In my asp.net application (vb on the server side) - I am using PageMethods in my javascript to make calls to some server side functions. One call in particular is not working properly. The pagemethods call is calling the server side function (as i can see by using tracepoints) - but the success or failure functions are not being hit after the function runs. I know the function on the server side is successfully running all the way to the end as the last bit of the function is a sql table update - which happens successfully. Can anyone tell me why the success or failure functions would not be called? Listed below is the call to the server side and the success and failure functions, as well as the server side function that is being called. Thank you for your help.

call to server side

```
PageMethods.UpdatePassword(document.getElementById('txtNewPass').value, updatePasswordCallBack, updatePasswordFail);
```

the success/fail functions

```
function updatePasswordCallBack(c) {
            alert('updatePasswordCallBack hit');
        }
function updatePasswordFail(c) {
            alert('updatePasswordFail hit');
        }
```

The server side function (which is called as can tell by tracepoints)

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function UpdatePassword(ByVal userText)
    'Open Connection to DB here, removed for stackoverflow post



    'convert userText to password hash removed for stack overflow


    'now must update the password

    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    myCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE P2_RESOURCE_PROFILE SET RES_PASSWORD = '" & userTextHash & "' WHERE RES_UID = " & UserID
    myCmd.ExecuteScalar()



    objConn.Close()

    Return true
End Function
```

So the executeScalar is being hit and changing the DB value, but no return or success function are hit when completed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Try using fiddler to debug the request so you can specify a most accurate exception

Comment: Thanks, even using fiddler I was not able to find the exact issue. I was able to put everything into one server side function - which ends up fixing this error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: when working this into one function, everything works fine in IE, but in firefox I am back to the issue where the success or failure are not being hit, but the server side function is called and completes successfully